# C++ optimise away private variable

Tags: c++

Does ISO C++ (11) permit a private non-static class member variable to be optimised away?
This could be detected:

```
class X { int x; };
assert (sizeof(X) >= sizeof(int));
```

but I am not aware of a clause that demands the assertion above.

To clarify: (a) Is there a clause in the C++ Standard that ensure the assertion above.

(b) Can anyone think of any other way to detect the elision of x?
[offsetof?]

(c) Is the optimisation permitted anyhow, despite (a) and (b)?

I have a feeling the optimisation could be possible if the class is local to a function but not otherwise (but I'd like to have a definitive citation).

Comment: What about a private member of a class with an external friend?

Comment: Just declaring a class isn't something that can be "optimized away" as it doesn't actually cause any code to be generated, and it doesn't need any space in the resulting object/executable file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I assume we're talking about instances of this class.

Comment: Private or public has nothing to do with it. The compiler can optimize anything away, as long as the code behaves "as if" there had been no optimization. Hence `sizeof` will not depend on optimization.

Comment: @juanchopanza in Java, public fields can never be optimised away. If a field is visible from outside its compilation unit, it cannot be removed by the compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza: your argument is fallacious.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `sizeof` does depend on optimization. What you probably meant is, `sizeof` doesn't depend on accessibility. Right?

Comment: @Nawaz I meant both actually, but if you have an example of the former, then I would be interested in knowing how it comes about. Is it somehow related to padding?

Comment: @juanchopanza: You need to learn some basic logic. If all black people in your class are women, and you're a woman, you cannot deduce that you're black. Just because all undetectedable changes are allowed optimisations doesn't imply all optimisations are undetectable. Introduction and elision of copy constructors is one example from C++. Its detectable but explicily allowed.

Comment: @Yttrill I did not say that all optimizations have to follow the "as if" rule. I think you are having some issues with logic.

Comment: Sigh. You said "hence sizeof doesn't depend on optimisations". You're argument is fallacious because you state it as the conclusion of the premise that all undetectedable changes are allowed optimisations. I agree with your premise but the conclusion does not follow from it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it was poorly phrased. I should have said something like "the sizeof assertion in your example is independent of optimizations."

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, padding and many other things, such as re-ordering of sections. Anyway, heard of empty-base-optimization? that does affect `sizeof`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Nawaz yes, I've heard of it. I just hadn't considered cases where it might *not* be applied. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @juanchopanza: you may be right the sizeof is invariant, but I want to see a citation from the ISO C++ Standard that prohibits, for example, a size of 0. Where does it say the size of a class has to be greater than or equal to the sum of the sizes of its members? For a struct, it doesn't have to say that, it can be deduced from other requirements.

Comment: @Yttrill *If* you can deduce it for a struct, then it should follow for a class, since the two are equivalent in C++ (the only difference being default access of members and base classes, which does not affect the object layout). But I haven't found a killer quote form the standard yet, only that `sizeof(SomeType)` is the number of bytes in an object of that type including padding. I am afraid it has to be pieced together from different sections.

Comment: @Yttrill: Actually, the Standard does require that any complete object has a size of a least one (and thus an address that is unique in the system) and that two objects of the same type have a different address. This leaves room for the Empty Base class optimization, or for sharing an address between an object and its base sub-object or for an object and an attribute of it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is forbidden, but I think it is impractical.

> **§9 Classes [class]**
>
> **7/** A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.107
>
> **8/** A **standard-layout struct** is a standard-layout class defined with the class-key `struct` or the class-key `class`.

... thus `class X { int x; };` is a standard-layout struct.

> **§9.2 Class members [class.mem]**
>
> **16/** Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9).

... thus `class X { int x; };` is layout-compatible with `struct Y { int y; };`.

The unfortunate thing is that layout-compatible is not formally defined in the Standard. However given the use of the word layout it seems the intent is to declare that two layout-compatible types should have the same underlying representation.

Therefore, to be able to remove the `x` in `X` one would have to prove that all structures that are *layout-compatible* (such as `Y`) are amenable to the same optimization (to keep the layout compatibility). It seems quite... improbable... in any non-trivial program.

Comment: Interesting argument! I have to agree with your conclusion. However, this just makes me change my example so that the rule doesn't apply: suppose we have one private int and one public one? Can the private one be elided?

Comment: @Yttrill: It's quite a different question, because the implementation only guarantees ordering of elements within the same access-specifier. Therefore the implementer gets much more freedom as soon as you start to mix them up, and I guess that elision could be possible then.

Comment: BTW: isn't "layout compatible" defined in the C Standard? If so, some of the front matter in the C++ Standard might include it by reference. Layout compatible is a vital concept in C, because you can have an anonymous struct typedefed in a header file shared between translation units. There's no One Definition Rule in C, so you cannot ask if the types are "the same" or not. You can ask if they're layout compatible.